# Upload image from local in js

Tags: javascript, knn

I'm trying to train a KNN to detect any weapons and dangerous object within luggage from X-RAY images found through Google and stored on my computer.

For now, I successfully implemented the KNN and the different class to train the program. However, until now my source for the training was a capture from the webcam video feed. Now I would like to replace the source by local images and it would need to work on p5js.org editor.

I didnt found any way to do this.
Do you get any idea to help me ?

The code is here
https://editor.p5js.org/arthurgyt/present/eYF_nB-i9

Thanks for your help and have a great evening !